# value from formnot entering into database in php

Tags: php

code is not coming into signup_ad.php

signup_ad.php:

```
 <? php
 mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("not connected");
 mysql_select_db("sample") or die("no db found");
 if(isset($_POST)
{
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];


$query= "insert into signup(fname,lname) values('$fname','$lname')";
$result=mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
$message='invalid query';
die($message); }
}
 ?>
```

value is not entering into db..and also not giving any error. Do i need to include my signup_ad.php file ?

signup.php:

```
<form action="signup_ad.php" method="post" >
  <label>
  First Name
  </label>
  <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" name="fname" />
  <label>
  Last Name
  </label>
  <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" name="lname"/>
  <button type="submit" class="button button-block" name="btn-signup"     value="submit" action="login.php" />Get Started</button>
```

Comment: Ouch! this is a nightmare waiting to happen: `mysql_` function, unsanitised inputs, what else?

Comment: Besides that typo mentioned by Giliaps your PHP code has major security issues. Any `mysql_*()` functions are deprecated since PHP 5.5. You should use `mysqli_*` instead. Furthermore, you should never insert parameters transferred from the client directly into a mysql statement. Use paramterized queries instead and always remember escaping those parameters to avoid SQL injections.

Comment: What do you mean `code is not coming in`? The `POST` is empty? Do you close the form? What's the `action="login.php"`?

Comment: i got security issues..but this values are not inserting into table..why ?

Comment: action login.php means after succesful insertion into table it should open login page

Comment: Have you tried any debugging so far? What are you trying to check by `if(isset($_POST)` this should always be true.

Comment: I think the form might be getting confused as it is being told to go to signup_ad.php but the submit button is telling the form to go to login.php

Comment: so what change i need to do ?

Comment: buttons don't use an action, the form does. Plus, we don't know if `<? php` is your actual syntax. You're using 2 different files also `action="signup_ad.php"` and `action="login.php"`.

Comment: it's also unknown if you did close off the form with `</form>`. So, check for errors via php's error reporting and on the query. *"and also not giving any error"* - That's because you're not checking for them and your system may not be set to do that by default.

Comment: i got the solution.. the problem was syntax error. i placeed <? php instead of <?php>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget a quotation before semicolon:

```
$query= "insert into signup(fname,lname) values('$fname','$lname')";
```